# Use Selenium to select an option from an Input element with multi-select drop-down

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error message when trying to select a drop-down value:

```
    UnexpectedTagNameException with message 'Element should have been "select" but was "input" error'
```

The Error is descriptive in saying that the element is an "Input" element instead of a "Select" element, but the field is actually a multi select drop-down which the user can typeinto or select.

I am using the following command:

```
    Select state = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("stateCode")));
    state.selectByIndex(6);
```

This is the HTML:

```HTML
    <div class="react-select__input" style="display: inline-block;">
     <input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="stateCode" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Is there another way to select the value from the drop-down?

Answer (score 2):

As per the html code attached you are accessing an `<input>` tag with `type='text'` (which means a text box).

We can use `Select` only on `<select>` tag like below:

```
<select id='mySelect'>
 <option value="1">1</option> 
</select>

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mySelect")));
```

Comment: *As per the html code attached* how do you know html code? OP didn't post one.

Comment: OP actually posted the html code but it was formatted incorrectly. Now with latest changes it is visible correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs because the drop which you are accessing using select class is wrong. Use `element.click();`

Then use element `sendkeys("your data here");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any of the below 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:** (I believe this will be the best approach to follow)

Click on the Input element which will pop your multi-select dropdown : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='stateCode']")).click();`

Find the desired value by using desired locator:
Ex: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(…)),`

**Approach 2:**

Type your desired value in the Input element   :  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='stateCode']")).sendKeys("DesiredCheckBoxOption");`

Click on the very first occurrence for checkbox by using desired locator (Ex: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(…)))`

Clear the input box:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='stateCode']")).clear();
```

Repeat  steps 1,2,3 for multiple selections (you can use a loop)